# The usual structure of $R[X]$-module of $M[X]$ is canonical

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, for a ring $R$. The $R$-module $M[X]$ is obviously an $R[X]$-module, but how is this structure canonical?

The data we start from is a ring map $R\to\operatorname{End}_\mathbb Z(M)$, and to give $M[X]$ an $R[X]$-module structure, we need a ring map $R[X]\to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb Z(M[X])$; that is, a ring map $R\to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb Z(M[X])$ together with an element of $ \operatorname{End}_\mathbb Z(M[X])$. I don't see why the usual choice of these data is not arbitrary but canonical in some sense.

The only thing I thought is that the usual structure of $R[X]$-module on $M[X]$ has the universal property of a left adjoint, i.e. any homomorphism of $R$-modules $M\to T$, for an $R[X]$-module $T$, factors in $M\to M[X]\to T$, with $M[X]\to T $ a homomorphism of $R[X]$-modules. However this property doesn't seem to hold for $M[X]$; do you have any other suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M[X]$ is the extension of scalars $M \otimes_R R[X]$ of $M$ from $R$ to $R[X]$, and so its $R[X]$-module structure is the one coming directly from this fact.

Comment: Thank you, now I see that, even without talking of tensor products, $M\mapsto M[X]$ is actually left adjoint to the restriction of scalars respect to $R\to R[X]$ (given $\varphi:M\to T$ as in the answer, $M[X]\to T$ is the linear extension of $mx^n\mapsto x^n\cdot \varphi(m)$).

Comment: @BradBitta: yes, that's the universal property of the extension of scalars.